# NOSQL : Data design formatting with json

Tags: cloudant, database, nosql

I am new to nosql and have very basic question but well aware of relational DB. 
I know how to create data in nosql db like say cloundant etc using json format. i can create new data where there is relationship like Employee and Dept etc..and put single json embedding say embedding employee referring Dept or vice versa.
{
  "_id": "xxx1",
  "employeeId": "3",
  "Depts":{
    "dept": "d1"
   }
}

Now if there a two data sets which has **no relationship** like say employee and Country list. Offcourse, I can create just new doc separately in DB but how to find/query them separately. 
If I have like 50 objects which i want to store. How do i store them so that i will be able retrieve with json query? and it practically usable when data is huge.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your questions: in the parameter juste before  your query , you can specify the dataset where you search your object.

Comment: You can either use multiple databases, or you can add type identifiers on your documents and create views to query based on type. I answered a similar question recently. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913228/can-i-create-multiple-collection-per-database/36915247#36915247